# How to show custom field (Account Number) on cash on delivery payment check?

Tags: magento-2.1.7

How to add custom field (Account Number) on cash on delivery payment check with it's additional data saved?

I have referred this link http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/save-payment-method-with-additional-data-show-custom-field-on-payment-check

as the above link saves data for bank transfer payment and i have replaced it with cash on delivery payment method.. i have applied the module but no changes..
Could someone guide me on this
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you run setup:upgrade and content deployment command after apply module ?

Comment: Yup, i have run the commands

Answer (score 0):

In your given link code is written for Bank transfer method. Try to check for bank transfer method. If you want to use this code for COD then need to change need to change in COD related file. Also need to change following condition

```
<?php if ($method == Banktransfer::PAYMENT_METHOD_BANKTRANSFER_CODE) :?>
<div class="admin__page-section-item-content">
    <strong><?php echo __('Account Name:') ?></strong>
    <span class="price"><?php echo $payment->getData('bankowner'); ?></span>                        
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here you need to replace Banktransfer::PAYMENT_METHOD_BANKTRANSFER_CODE to your COD related code.

Comment: I have replaced it with Cash on delivery but no effect at.. i don't know where i made mistake..

Comment: In which file you have replaced ?

Comment: Check out  my file path TemplateMonster/Cashondeliveries/view/adminhtml/templates/info/cashondeliveryinfo.phtml

Comment: In above file path i have replaced it with COD

Comment: As per your given example, need to call your cod phtml file form xml as given on that page.
<referenceContainer name="payment_additional_info">
            <block class="Ibnab\Additional\Block\Info\BanktransferInfo" name="ibnab_banktransfert_infos" template="Ibnab_Additional::info/banktransferinfo.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>

Comment: Also can you please make sure code is working for bank transfer method by enable bank transfer method, If everything is ok then need to write code for COD. So we can know where doing mistake.

Comment: Okay i wil check with bank transfer method.. then i wil let you know

Comment: I checked with banktranfer method also but no effect at all

Comment: It means this module is not working properly. Try this 
https://webkul.com/blog/add-cc-form-custom-payment-method-magento2/
They will have add section for CC. It will help you to add new text box.

Comment: The link you shared is to create a completely new form.. but i just want to add a input field with its data saved in db and backend

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on my screen shot. i have applied the module for banktranfer method but no changes at all.. not even showing any errors.

[image]